# Android session starts at same time

Tags: android

I am working with one game which is basically a location based game. The duration of game is 5 mins. Everything is working fine. But the problem is on one device game is starting before the  game is started on the other device.

Suppose User A has sent request, user b has accepted the request. then only game screen should appear. But in my case its not happening.

Can anybody help me to give me the logic to start the game between two devices at the same time without a second delay. I am using web service for sending the game requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought:

You might use some sort of [Mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) on the server side that tries to determine if both clients are ready.

This is assuming the game is run on a server as you described, and not peer to peer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this might help. try using some sort of command that the server sends to client and then only game starts on both the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe user B starts when the he accepts but user A hasn't actually received the response yet...or something in that scenario.

How about when user B accepts, take the time (server time to ensure same time) and start around X (10 or 15) seconds after? then send that time (time, not duration) to user A as well. In this case, both user A and user B will just be waiting for the appointed time and then start at the same time? Just an idea, implementation is all up to you :)